# MySQL connection gone

Tags: php, mysql, azure, cleardb

I am using `clearDB` database for my `windows azure` based `php` application. I am getting intermittent error on `mysql` connections. Currently we have nearly **2000 online customers**. And we have **30 connections** from database.

How can I scale the website and overcome this situation?

I am taking care of closing connection most of the times. For now I have prevented server errors by this:

```
try {
   $this->_conn = $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
   $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   die("Couldn't connect to database. Please try again!");
}
```

So, if there is no connections left, then it'll show appropriate message. But, It's not feasible for customer facing websites. How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**

How can I analyse this data:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Variable_name] => Connections
        [Value] => 505369
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Variable_name] => Threads_cached
        [Value] => 54
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Variable_name] => Threads_connected
        [Value] => 65
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Variable_name] => Threads_created
        [Value] => 1038
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Variable_name] => Threads_running
        [Value] => 4
    )
)
```

I got above result after: `SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE 'Threads_%' OR variable_name = 'Connections'`

Comment: I would suggest taking this over to ServerFault or similar. Sounds like you need to sort your DB settings / general infrastructure rather than there being anything to be done programatically with what's provided..

Comment: Typical performance troubleshooting for MySQL includes turning on the slow_query_log, running a tuning analyzer such as mysqltuner.pl, checking DB normalization, etc.  What have you done so far?

Comment: @Kkinsey: I don't know any one of those tools that you mentioned.

Comment: The slow_query_log is a feature of the MySQL server; enable it in "my.cnf" and then read the logfile to see which queries need improvement.  See, for example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: If you're seeing persistent issues using ClearDB then you should consider moving to a self-managed MySQL instance running on an Azure VM.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding of the issue, it is not easy to design a scalable database. Consider the following suggestions:

- Use connection pools. A connection pool will try to automatically
  reuse an existing connection whenever possible. So the 30 connections
  may be used by more than 30 concurrent users. Please refer to
  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.pooling.php for more information.
- Partition the database. That is, if one database is insufficient, 
  then use multiple. This is a bit huge topic, you can begin from 
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html. 
  Those guidelines for Azure SQL Databases 
  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495641.aspx) can 
  also help, while the database engine is different, most concepts are 
  the same.
- Use in memory storage. MySQL currently does not offer a    complete
  set of in-memory database features. But the MEMORY Storage    Engine
  could help. In-memory storage can usually improve performance    a
  lot. But please note there’re some limitations. This is actually
  one area where major database vendors (including open source) are 
  continuously investing. And remember if the database server does not 
  have sufficient memory, it will not help at all. Please check 
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html to
  see if helps.